# Can't change max_input_vars limit in php.ini

Tags: php

I need to change PHP max_input_vars variable but after change in php.ini and server restart phpinfo shows old value all the time. This is what i do:

in phpinfo() i've got

```
...
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini
...
max_input_vars  1000
```

from server CL I've edit /etc/php.ini and uncomment line with max_input_vars it looks like this:

```
...
max_input_vars = 5000
...
```

after this changes and restarting web server

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

phpinfo still shows max_input_vars as 1000
It looks like php use some other php.ini or values are overwritten because with other settings like max_execution_time is the same.

If i'm doing it wrong way? Is this possible that phpinfo shows different configuration file than the one used?

phpinfo output:

[image: phpinfo output]

Comment: Did you restart your Apache/Nginx? That usually does  the trick.

Comment: Are you looking at `phpinfo` output in a script triggered via the web server, or on the command line? The PHP embedded into the web server, and the CLI version, often use different php.ini files.

Comment: what @CBroe said is basically a pro tip and usually what causes these differences

Comment: Did you actually look at the "Local Value" part (and not the "Master Value")? Did you `sudo` edit the `php.ini`, have the changes been saved?

Comment: @CBroe yes, i'm looking at phpinfo output from a script.

Comment: @brombeer both values are 1000. Yes, changes were saved

Comment: @Zegert yes i've run systemctl restart httpd

Comment: Please post your entire `phpinfo();` output, so we can help determine the php configuration values for your environment. My guess is that you are using PHP-FPM.

Comment: @Will B. How to paste in so much information that it remains legible? But yes in phpinfo output there is "Server API  FPM/FastCGI"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're using [PHP-FPM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php), you need to check it's configs for overrides, typically in `/etc/php-fpm/*.conf`.

```
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = XXX
```

After validating there are no overrides that affect your settings, restart the php-fpm service and as a best-practice also Apache.

```
systemctl restart php-fpm httpd
```

Restarting the PHP-FPM service is required because Apache passes requests to the running PHP instance(s) loaded into memory from the PHP-FPM service. As PHP is already loaded into memory by PHP-FPM, the PHP-FPM service needs to be restarted for PHP configuration changes to be applied.

Apache prior to PHP-FPM typically relied on starting the PHP process using the Apache [`mod_php`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php), thereby requiring the restarting of the Apache service for configuration changes to be applied immediately, or until `mod_php` reloaded the PHP instance.

---

Based on your configuration, you should add additional PHP config settings to `/etc/php.d/zzz-custom.ini` instead of `/etc/php.ini`. PHP will load the config files in alphabetical order, resulting in the `zzz-custom.ini` file being loaded last and be used as the final values of the PHP settings.
Using the `/etc/php.d/zzz-custom.ini` file will also prevent the loss of your custom php.ini settings and the need to make extensive changes to the default `/etc/php.ini` file when updating PHP versions.
However, `/etc/php-fpm/*.conf` settings will take precedent over any `/etc/php.d/*.ini` configs.

Comment: In my case it was enough to restart php-fpm. Thank You

Answer (score -2):

first: Method is edit the PHP. ini file
Locate your PHP. ini file. ...
If you find your existing PHP. ini, open the file and locate the following line of code (xx represents a number): max_input_vars = xx ; And set it to your desired limit. ...
If you created your own PHP. ...
Save your changes, and reboot your localhost or your server.

Comment: The OP wrote in the question and comments that was already tested. The question was why that setting is not used despite changing it and restarting the server.

Comment: Rebooting a whole server is usually not neccessary for configuration changes